# Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Unsupported operand types: int + string on PHP 8.0.8

Tags: php, php-8

Im converting number format like 35,578,926 to short word like 35.5M (or million). My code works fine on PHP 7.4, on the latest version 8.0.8 the fatal error occurs.

```
function convert($n)
{
    $n = (0 + str_replace(",", "", $n));
    if (!is_numeric($n)) return false;
    if ($n > 1000000000000) return round(($n / 1000000000000) , 1) . 'T';
    else if ($n > 1000000000) return round(($n / 1000000000) , 1) . 'B';
    else if ($n > 1000000) return round(($n / 1000000) , 1) . 'M';
    else if ($n > 1000) return round(($n / 1000) , 1) . 'K';
    return number_format($n);
}
$n = '35578926';
```

On PHP 7.4 this code returns the output:

```
$n = convert('35578926'); 
echo $n; // 35.5M
```

I tried changing

```
$n = (0 . str_replace(",", "", $n)); // this resolve nothing but no error 


$n = null; // also this resolve nothing but no error
```

So how do i convert this number (35578926 or 35,578,926) into short word like 35.5M on PHP 8.0.8?

Comment: Your code isn't kicking out any warnings for me: https://3v4l.org/Qdl5V However you could also just force-cast to int or float inside

Comment: What's the error you're getting? I have access to only 8.0.0, and your code works okay.

Comment: I got this 'Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Unsupported operand types: int + string' on php 8.0.8 xampp

Comment: I read about that somewhere: changing the casting rules so that constructions like `'0e55' == '0e99'` don't return `true`. I'd change the assignment line to `$n = intval(str_replace(",", "", $n));`

Comment: It works by changing to ```$n = intval(str_replace(",", "", $n)); ```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Unsupported operand types: string + int in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66238017/fatal-error-uncaught-typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-string-int-in)

Comment: I already mentioned it on my questions, i tried 2 changes but still not working. @YiminRong solution worked for me

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this line of code was written by someone more familiar with JavaScript  (or some other language) than PHP:

```
$n = (0 + str_replace(",", "", $n));
```

In JavaScript, the "0 +" here is an idiomatic way of forcing a value to be a "number" rather than a string. However, in PHP, there are [explicit cast operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) for that purpose, as well as separate integer and floating-point types, so the line should be either:

```
$n = (int)str_replace(",", "", $n);
```

or:

```
$n = (float)str_replace(",", "", $n);
```

There is also another bug here, which is that this line happens too late:

```
if (!is_numeric($n)) return false;
```

Currently, this is run *after* converting the string into a number, so it is impossible for it not to be numeric. This would make more sense:

```
$n = str_replace(",", "", $n);
if (!is_numeric($n)) return false;
$n = (float)$n;
```

Note that [is_numeric](https://www.php.net/is_numeric) has a very broad definition of "numeric", so if you actually just want integers, you probably want [ctype_digit](https://www.php.net/ctype_digit) instead:

```
$n = str_replace(",", "", $n);
if (!ctype_digit($n)) return false;
$n = (int)$n;
```